# Deserializing nested json's with jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

This is an extension to my previous question 
[Extract specific value from complex JSON in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11844180/extract-specific-value-from-complex-json-in-java). I have got the solution, but I wanted to try extracting 3 values from the json string with bean class. For the given json structure. json structure is in the link.

I'm using the following code to call jackson:

```
mainbean obj = mapper.readValue(file, mainbean.class);
System.out.println(obj.clientPayload.e.h.getAk());
```

I have generated POJOs for the whole hiearchy where the mainbean class looks like:

```
public class mainbean {
    public Cpld cp;

    public Cpld getCp() {
        return Cp;
    }

    public void setCp(Cpld cp) {
        this.cp= cp;
    }
    public SPL getSp() {
        return sp;
    }
    public void setSp(SPL sp) {
        this.sp= sp;
    }
    private SPL sp;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "mainbean [cp=" + cp+ "]";
    }
}
```

followed by Cpld class

```
public class Cpld {
    public E e;

    public E getE() {
        return e;
    }

    public void setE(E e) {
        this.e = e;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return "E string" + e;
    }
}
```

then e class

```
public class E {
    public H h;

    public H getH() {
        return h;
    }
    public void setH(H h) {
        this.h = h;
    }
    public C c;
    public B b;
    public TT tt;
    public C getC() {
        return c;
    }
    public void setC(C c) {
        this.c = c;
    }
    public B getB() {
        return b;
    }
    public void setB(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
    public TT getTt() {
        return tt;
    }
    public void setTt(TT tt) {
        this.tt = tt;
    }
}
```

and so on... I am getting an exception

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class JsonPath.Cpld] from JSON String; no single-String constructor/factory method (through reference chain: JsonPath.mainbean["clientPayload"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator._createFromStringFallbacks(StdValueInstantiator.java:419)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.createFromString(StdValueInstantiator.java:295)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromString(BeanDeserializer.java:405)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:117)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:336)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:89)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:290)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:112)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2577)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1764)
```

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction here... 
Thanks in advance for any help

Update:
Json file : [Extract specific value from complex JSON in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11844180/extract-specific-value-from-complex-json-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Because the top JSON object's value for `CP` is a string representation of a JSON object, not a JSON object itself, your `Cpld` class needs an explicit constructor that takes a string and deserializes it into the properties of this object.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an empty constructor to your Clpd class